# Can Symantec Trial Certificate be used for easy man in the middle attacks?

Tags: tls, certificates, man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority

Symantec SSL Trial Certificate issues certificates without validation that the domain is owned by the one requesting the certificate. Doesn't this make it easy to do a man in the middle attack against any websites?

For more information see [Symantec Trial Certificate Website][1]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've edited the question because it was hardly possible to understand what you were asking. Please check if the edit reflects what you've tried to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSL certificate issued using this process is not trusted by default by any software and thus cannot do any harm as long as the software is doing proper validation of certificates. And if the software is not doing proper validation there is no hope for this software anyway, i.e. you don't need this trial certificate but can create your own.

From [the documentation](https://knowledge.symantec.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7040):

> In order to test the use of a Symantec SSL Trial certificate, you **must install a special Symantec Trial Intermediate and Symantec Trial Root CA** on the server. The Trial Root **must also be installed in each browser** that will be used during the testing phase. This is a special step that Symantec has implemented **to prevent fraudulent use of trial certificates**. When purchasing a production SSL certificate, these additional steps are not necessary.

Comment: I just make my trial and it's work they trust my certificate in browser with Apache 2 server

Comment: @sami: I have no idea how you tested but it should only work if you've explicitly included the Trial Root CA into your browser. Otherwise the validation should fail, i.e browser should show an appropriate warning.

Comment: i never import Trial Root CA into my browser and it's work!! they trust certificate with any website except wildcard and facebook and google when import csr to Symantec

Comment: @sami: If the site is public please offer the link so I can check myself. If not please provide the certificate or at least a screenshot of the trust chain as seen in the browser so one can have some way to verify what you say.

Comment: just one moment

Comment: gave my a website to obtain certificate prefer not widely know website

Comment: i just edit my post

Comment: @sami: this certificate shows clearly that it is issued by the Symantec Trial CA. This CA should not be trusted by the computer by default. Could you please also show the certification path so that one can see what the builtin trusted root is for this certificate?

Comment: ok one moment i well edit my post

Comment: @sami: This shows (as expected) Verisign Trial Secure Server Root CA - G2 as the trusted root. This means that someone must have explicitly added this Root CA to your system as trusted because it is not included in normal systems. Please check with another machine or a fresh system.

Comment: i have another laptop i well check it and tell you the result